# How to skip a map of map when deserialize from Json String to Object using object mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a map of map in my POJO which is always null. When i convert a json string to java object, then i am getting a deserialization error because of the map. So how can i skip the map while converting the json string to object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of those will probably solve the problem:

1. you may define the field `transient`, like:

   ```
   private transient Map<String, String> mapOfSomething;
   ```
2. (or) you can add `@JsonIgnore` annotation, like:

   ```
   @JsonIgnore
   private Map<String, String> mapOfAnotherThing;
   ```